# How can I trim whitespace from results of preg_match_all in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Given the function:

```
function getUrlsAndEmails($string) {
    $regex = '/(?:[^\s]+@[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)+)|(?:(?:(?:[a-z]+:\/\/)|\s)[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)+(\/[^\s]*)?)/';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    return ($matches[0]);
}
```

Sometimes return results like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => google.com
    [1] =>  yahoo.com
)
```

How can I efficiently trim whitespace from all results of a `preg_match_all()`?

Of course I can loop through all of the results and `trim()`, but is there a more efficient way than adding this to the function above:

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $k => $v) {
    $matches[0][$k] = trim($v);
}
```

Comment: Use `array_walk` or `array_map` For simple iteration

Comment: "a more efficient way" --- efficient from what perspective?

Comment: efficient = less lines, more elegant, faster, easier to read.  Or just look to @Razvan's answer below. See, no more lines necessary.

Comment: @Ryan: "easier to read" --- "Or just look to Razvan's answer below" o_O

Comment: Well the Regex is their either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$regex = '/(?:[^\s]+@[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)+)|(?:(?:(?:[a-z]+:\/\/)|(?!\s))[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)+(\/[^\s]*)?)/';
```

It uses a negative lookahead assertion for the space.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map('trim')`.

```php
<?php
$pattern = Pattern::of('(?:[^\s]+@[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)+)|(?:(?:(?:[a-z]+:\/\/)|\s)[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)+(\/[^\s]*)?)');
$matcher = $pattern->match($string);
   
var_dump($matcher->map('trim'));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'google.com'
    [1] => 'yahoo.com'
)
```